# DPI settings in Awesome window manager

Tags: xrandr, awesome, dpi

I have a nice new shiny 4k monitor. I can increase the font size for most applications (including awesome) however, there are a few issues:

1. The wibar vicious widgets show a tiny font, not the one defined in `theme.lia`.
2. Any Gnome applications still show the old (aka tiny) font size.

I suspect that setting the font size everywhere will lead me going insane. Is there a DPI setting within `Awesome` I can use?

If not, is there some `xrandr` magic I can do?

Comment: AFAIK xrandr can only do some scaling, but then you wouldn't need the 4k monitor. But you could keep it in mind in case you want to connect a lower dpi screen as well.

Comment: @JakobLenfers Login in using Gnome does some scaling so there is the ability in there to do it. How it does it, that's the question.

Comment: Maybe you'll find something useful here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/HiDPI

Comment: @JakobLenfers That's currently the best I have…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## An inelegant hack!

Currently, I am using a mix of

```
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --scale 0.8x0.8
export GDK_SCALE=2
export GDK_DPI_SCALE=0.6
```

And setting fonts. Mostly, it was taken from [Arch Linux's section on HiDPI](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/HiDPI).

Not elegant at all ☹

## A real solution…

### Background

[Issue 760](https://github.com/awesomeWM/awesome/issues/760) suggests that the current master branch of awesome does support custom DPI. And [issue 1225](https://github.com/awesomeWM/awesome/issues/1225) is my attempt at doing things properly.

### Install `master` branch

```
sudo dnf uninstall awesome #  ← This might unisntall dependencies, re-install those!
sudo dnf install -y xorg-x11-server-Xephyr
cd ~/src/awesome # Or where ever the source is.
rm -r .build*
```

You now need to apply [this patch](https://github.com/awesomeWM/awesome/issues/1234), once that'd done resume:

```
make CMAKE_ARGS="-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/usr -DAWESOME_DOC_PATH=/usr/share/doc/awesome -DSYSCONFDIR=/etc " all package
sudo rpm --vv --install build/awesome*rpm
Xephyr :1 &
DISPLAY=:1 awesome -c /etc/xdg/awesome/rc.lua
```

If the above works, you should be nearly there. If not, use `dnf` to install `awesome`.

### Nearly done, just some book keeping left.

You old configuration will not longer work, so you need to get [the files from the xresources theme](https://github.com/awesomeWM/awesome/tree/master/themes/xresources) as well as the default `rc.lua` file.  I would strongly recommend you take a backup of the old configuration, but really what could go wrong⸮

Your `~/.Xresources` could look like this:

```
Xft.dpi:        156
Xft.antialias:  true
Xft.hinting:    true
Xft.rgba:       rgb
Xft.hintstyle:  hintslight
```

Make sure you disable `awesome` from being updated via `dnf` by adding `exclude=awesome` to `/etc/dnf/dnf.conf`.

Finally, log out (reboot, whatever) and log back in: you should now be ready.

Comment: If `y` is omitted from scale, the `x` is used for both, simplifying the first line of you hack to: `xrandr --output HDMI-1 --scale 0.8`.

Answer (score 13):

With awesome 4.0 on Debian stretch, no patch as in the answer of Sardathrion is needed, that is to change your dpi to get a proper screen setup, you need to

1) Create the .Xresources file with your settings, that is 

`Xft.dpi: 192`

If you are wondering about the right DPI value, see this [post](https://winaero.com/blog/find-change-screen-dpi-linux/). I used the next value that was a multiple of 96.

For more interesting settings, check out the informative [Arch wiki entry](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/x_resources)

2) I needed to include the settings from .Xresources by adding the following line to the file .xinitrc

`xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources`

Comment: Thanks for this great answer. Could you please tell me where the magic number 96 comes from?

Comment: Worked for me too.

Answer (score 1):

On my Laptop with 3200x1800px I can set the scaling to 0.5 which displays everything correctly with:

```
xrandr --output $(xrandr|head -n2|tail -n1|cut -d\  -f 1) --scale 0.5x0.5
```

But the drawback is, that this renders the text really **blurry**

A solution with a sharper display is setting the resolution of the screen to half size with

```
xrandr -s 1600x900
```

This works quite well for some applications, for example Firefox looks perfect, but for example chrome has a big problem with that solution and displays all gui-menues in a really tiny font. A workaround for this I found by starting chromium on the console with

```
chromium-browser --force-device-scale-factor=1.0
```

So it seems you have to adapt many applications by hand this way.